# What do fsync() do when open() with O_DIRECT in ext4

Tags: file, ext4, fsync

I know XFS does not sync metadata even though the file being written is open with `O_DIRECT` and the metadata of the file is changed. But for ext4, I notice that MySQL support `O_DIRECT_NO_FSYNC` which means MySQL does not call `fsync()` and lets the filesystem sync metadata by itself.

So here comes the question: if I `open` a file with `O_DIRECT` in ext4 (say linux kernel version 5.8.0), and call `fsync()` after `write()`, what will `fsync()` do?

Another question to follow: what will `fsync()` do if `open()` a file with `O_DIRECT | O_SYNC` in ext4?

Thanks!

Comment: (Please stick to one question per, um, question!)

Answer (score 1):

[`O_DIRECT` does not imply anything about a disk's own volatile cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49462406/2732969). On Linux `fsync()` can request for data in that cache to be written back too.

As for your `fsync()` when the file is already using `O_DIRECT|O_SYNC`... There will be overhead because you made a syscall, the page cache will have to be checked and that disk cache flush will be sent - they just won't have any work to do so it's something of a waste. I guess you could end up flushing data for the journal and/or another file depending on the filesystem.