# DIRECT I/O performance

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I am trying to measure DIRECT IO performance. By my understanding DIRECT I/O ignores the page cache and goes to the underlying device to fetch the data. Therefore, if we are reading the same file over and over again, DIRECT I/O would be slower compared to accesses involving the page cache as the file would be cached.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

char *DIRECT_FILE_PATH = "direct.dat";
char *NON_DIRECT_FILE_PATH = "no_direct.dat";
int FILE_SIZE_MB = 100;
int NUM_ITER = 100;

void lay_file(int direct_flag) {
    int flag = O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_DIRECT;
    mode_t mode = 0644;

    int fd;
    if (direct_flag) {
        fd = open(DIRECT_FILE_PATH, flag, mode);
    } else {
        fd = open(NON_DIRECT_FILE_PATH, flag, mode);
    }

    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("Failed to open file. Error: \t%s\n", strerror(errno));
    } 

    ftruncate(fd, FILE_SIZE_MB*1024*1024);
    close(fd);
}

void read_file(int direct_flag) {

    mode_t mode = 0644;
    void *buf = malloc(FILE_SIZE_MB*1024*1024);

    int fd, flag;
    if (direct_flag) {
        flag = O_RDONLY | O_DIRECT;
        fd = open(DIRECT_FILE_PATH, flag, mode);
    } else {
        flag = O_RDONLY;
        fd = open(NON_DIRECT_FILE_PATH, flag, mode);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<NUM_ITER; i++) {
        read(fd, buf, FILE_SIZE_MB*1024*1024);
        lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
    }
    close(fd);
}

int main() {

    lay_file(0);
    lay_file(1);

    clock_t t;
    t = clock();
    read_file(1);
    t = clock() - t;
    double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds
    printf("DIRECT I/O read took %f seconds to execute \n", time_taken);

    t = clock();
    read_file(0);
    t = clock() - t;
    time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds
    printf("NON DIRECT I/O read took %f seconds to execute \n", time_taken);

    return 0;
}
```

Using the above code to measure DIRECT I/O performance tells me that DIRECT I/O is faster than regular IO involving the page cache. This is the output

**
DIRECT I/O read took 0.824861 seconds to execute
NON DIRECT I/O read took 1.643310 seconds to execute
**

Please let me know if I am missing something. I have an NVMe SSD as the storage device. I wonder if it is too fast to really show the difference in performance of when the page cache is used and not used.

UPDATE:

Changing the buffer size to 4KB shows that DIRECT I/O is slower. The large buffer size was probably making large sequential writes to the underlying device which is more helpful but would still like some insights.

** DIRECT I/O read took 0.000209 seconds to execute NON DIRECT I/O read took 0.000151 seconds to execute **

Comment: [clock manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html): "*returns an approximation of processor time*". That is, doesn't include I/O time - the very thing you are trying to measure.

Comment: By DIRECT I/O, I understand, "don't do caching", am I right? For measurements, you can explore some profiling tool like `perf`. It may have some ways to measure I/O time.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/41257656/1216776