# Why is writing files witht syscall.O_DIRECT flag make writing files slower in go?

Tags: go, filesystems, file-writing

I've got a small peice of code named `test.go`. It counts time(ns) when doing two writings that write a same byte slice to 2 files, one with the flag `syscall.O_DIRECT` and the other not.

The code is below:

```golang
package main;

import (
        "os"
        "time"
        "fmt"
        "strconv"
        "bytes"
        "syscall"
        // "os/exec"
)
func main() {
        num, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1]);
        writeContent:= bytes.Repeat( ([]byte)("1"), num );
        t1:= time.Now().UnixNano();
        fd1, err := syscall.Open("abc.txt", syscall.O_WRONLY | syscall.O_DIRECT | syscall.O_TRUNC, 0);
        syscall.Write(fd1, writeContent);
        if err != nil {panic(err);}
        t2:= time.Now().UnixNano();
        fmt.Println("sysW1:", t2-t1);

        t1= time.Now().UnixNano();
        fd2, err := syscall.Open("abc.txt", syscall.O_WRONLY | syscall.O_TRUNC, 0);
        syscall.Write(fd2, writeContent);
        if err != nil {panic(err);}
        t2= time.Now().UnixNano();
        fmt.Println("sysW2:", t2-t1);
}
```

The program is runned in linux command line like this:(after being compiled with `go build ./test.go`)

```
./test 1024
```

I had expected writing file with `syscall.O_DIRECT` flag to be faster, but the result showed that writing files with `syscall.O_DIRECT` flag was about **30** times slower than writing without it :(

result:

```
sysW1: 1107377
sysW2: 37155
```

Why? I tought writing with syscall.O_DIRECT does less copying and would be faster, but it now turns out to be much slower. Please help me explain it :(

PX: I will not provide playground link since the result is always 0 when running the program on the playground in some reason.

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. a) it is a hint that may be ignored and b) if it is not ignored, it will bypass the cache so it will wait until the write to the device is complete, so it will take longer than when the write call uses the cache and completes before the data is physically written to the device. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41257656/what-does-o-direct-really-mean

Comment: When you say "would be faster", do you mean the write would hit the storage faster? Or do you mean the system call would return faster?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks, do you know any writing method as fast as writing without `syscall.O_DIRECT` flag but releases the system cache after writing? I mean, I don't want the cache to take too much space in RAM

Comment: The cache is considered free available memory in Linux. If a process needs memory that is occupied by the cache, the kernel will flush/release the cache at that point. The cache doesn't "use up" memory so you don't need to release it.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thank you very much. Would you like to write this as an answer so that I could accept it? :)

Comment: Cache means fast and direct (=no cache) means slow. Modern hardware is _complicated_ and naive guesses (even guesses based on year long experience and fundamental understanding of all involved components) and expectations are wrong in almost all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`O_DIRECT` doesn't do what you think. While it does less memory copying (since it doesn't copy to the cache before copying to the device driver), that doesn't give you a performance boost.

The filesystem cache ensures that the system call can return early before the data is written to the device, and buffer data to send data in larger chunks.

With `O_DIRECT`, the system call waits until the data is completely transferred to the device.

From the [man page for the `open` call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

> `O_DIRECT` (since Linux 2.4.10)
>
> Try to minimize cache effects of the I/O to and from this
> file.  *In general this will degrade performance*, but it is
> useful in special situations, such as when applications do
> their own caching.  File I/O is done directly to/from
> user-space buffers.  The `O_DIRECT` flag on its own makes an
> effort to transfer data synchronously, but does not give
> the guarantees of the `O_SYNC` flag that data and necessary
> metadata are transferred.

See also: [What does O_DIRECT really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41257656/what-does-o-direct-really-mean)

You don't need to manually release the cache after using it.
The cache is considered free available memory by the Linux kernel. If a process needs memory that is occupied by the cache, the kernel will flush/release the cache at that point. The cache doesn't "use up" memory.